# T-SQL Trigger throws: The row value(s) updated or deleted either do no make the row unique or they alter multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The trigger below is defined on one of the three related tables and it updates another table. However it doesn't work. Instead it throws:

*The data in row 3 was not committed.
Error Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.
Error message: The row value(s) updated or deleted either do no make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(24 rows).*

```
CREATE TABLE [Develop].[TemplateSqlProjects]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Develop.TemplateSqlProjects] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Develop_TemplateSqlProjects_Name_Unique]
    ON [Develop].[TemplateSqlProjects]([Name] ASC);
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [Develop].[TemplateSqlStatements]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SqlStatement] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Develop.TemplateSqlStatements] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Develop.TemplateSqlStatements_Develop.TemplateSqlProjects_ProjectId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectId]) REFERENCES [Develop].[TemplateSqlProjects] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [Develop].[TemplateSqlStatementGuids]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SqlStatementId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Guid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Develop.TemplateSqlStatementGuids] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Develop.TemplateSqlStatementGuids_Develop.TemplateSqlStatements_SqlStatementId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([SqlStatementId]) REFERENCES [Develop].[TemplateSqlStatements] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [SqlStatementId_Guid_Unique]
    ON [Develop].[TemplateSqlStatementGuids]([SqlStatementId] ASC, [Guid] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Develop_TemplateSqlStatementGuids_Guid]
    ON [Develop].[TemplateSqlStatementGuids]([Guid] ASC);
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER [Develop].[Trigger_Develop_TemplateSqlStatements_AfterInsertOrUpdate] ON [Develop].[TemplateSqlStatements]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM Develop.TemplateSqlStatementGuids
    WHERE SqlStatementId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED);

    DELETE FROM Develop.TemplateSqlStatementGuids
    WHERE SqlStatementId IN (SELECT Id FROM INSERTED);

    INSERT INTO Develop.TemplateSqlStatementGuids (SqlStatementId, [Guid])
    SELECT DISTINCT i.Id, f.Value
    FROM INSERTED i
    CROSS APPLY Utility.ft_ExtractGuids(i.SqlStatement) f
    ORDER BY i.Id, f.Value

END
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE FUNCTION [Utility].[ft_ExtractGuids] (@Text NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Guids TABLE ( Value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IndexStart AS BIGINT;
    DECLARE @IndexEnd AS BIGINT;
    SELECT @IndexStart = PATINDEX(N'%' + REPLACE(N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', N'0', N'[0-9a-fA-F]') + N'%', @Text)
    WHILE @IndexStart > 0 AND LEN(@Text) > 36
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Guids (Value) VALUES (TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, SUBSTRING(@Text, @IndexStart, 36)));
            SET @Text = SUBSTRING(@Text, @IndexStart + 36, LEN(@Text) - 36);
            SET @IndexStart = PATINDEX(N'%' + REPLACE(N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', N'0', N'[0-9a-fA-F]') + N'%', @Text);
        END
    DELETE FROM  @Guids WHERE Value = N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
    RETURN;
END
```

It seems like it should work. The values are unique. I've tried many variations such as eliminating the `, DELETE` action, inserting into a *temp* table without constraints, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: That function makes me cry. What is it doing? Multi-statement table valued functions are often even slower than scalar functions.

Comment: Id is an identity column. Speed is not the concern here. I use this table to generate a bunch of code snippets using a common query. Snippets are delimited by GUIDs. Since C# support is temporarily suspended in Azure SQL Database, I'm using T-SQL's PATINDEX as a regex substitute to extract the GUIDs.

Comment: Do you have any other triggers? Have you confirmed 100% that it's the INSERT line in this trigger that's the issue? I suggest you remove the `ORDER BY` in your trigger - it's not doing anything.

Comment: There are no other triggers (or relationships). It seems like `INSERT` is the issue in that the error message indicates "altering multiple rows". Without the insert, it wouldn't be altering them. Since generally there are multiple `Value`s per `Id`,  `ORDER BY` should be affecting the insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below select that you are trying to insert into TemplateSqlStatementGuids table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Id, f.Value
    FROM INSERTED i
    CROSS APPLY Utility.ft_ExtractGuids(i.SqlStatement) f
    ORDER BY i.Id, f.Value
```

It seems you are trying to insert f.value into guid column using cross apply. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Each f.Value is a GUID.